# Daily part of cron code doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a cron file that works just fine but yesterday I decided to add a code to my website and it requires daily reset. Here is the code that I added to the cron file:

```
$db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET `level_reward_claimed`='1' WHERE `level_reward_claimed`>'1'");
```

It's supposed to reset "level_reward_claimed" to 1 for all members if their "level_reward_claimed" > 1.

Now, the problem is that it doesn't reset "level_reward_claimed" for any members even if they have "level_reward_claimed" > 1. I have similar codes in the cron file and they work just fine:

```
$db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET `ytlbonus`='0' WHERE `ytlbonus`='1'");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your could get your SQL fixed - maybe this helps?

```
UPDATE `users` SET `level_reward_claimed`=1 WHERE `level_reward_claimed`>1
UPDATE `users` SET `ytlbonus`=0 WHERE `ytlbonus`=1
```

and secondly, you should use mysq event scheduler to execute SQL statements on a regular basis. read more here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET `level_reward_claimed`=1 WHERE `level_reward_claimed`>1");
```

Probably are using integers not strings.

Alternatively output  the error message if the query fails